# What is the baseline of a RGBD camera?

Tags: cameras, calibration

I'm looking at some [ORB SLAM2 settings](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2/blob/master/Examples/RGB-D/TUM1.yaml) where there's a parameter for "IR projector baseline times fx". Could someone here explain what exactly is the baseline of an IR projector? Is it the distance between the IR projector lens and the IR camera lens? OR is it between the RGB camera and the IR camera?